# Use value of variable as object index

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

I want to use the value of a variable as an "index" of an object, an of a value inside of it.
Unfortunately this code won't run.

```
            animatedObjects = {
                userPosition.uid: {
                    "uid": userPosition.uid,
                    "x": 30,
                    "y": 31
                }
            }
```

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Can you please post more of your code and what values the variables contain? The second example should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userPosition.uid` is probably not working. You're also missing a closing brace.

Here's a minimal example which shows the concept working. If you have `userPosition.uid` working, your example is all good. Check you can output just `userPosition.uid`.

```
a = {}
b = {c: 3}
a[b.c] = 5
a  // now equal to {3: 5}
```

Comment: Indeed, I must have done something wrong with userPosition.uid, because that method now does work.

Answer (score 0):

```
animatedObjects = {
    userPosition.uid: { // pos 1
    "uid": userPosition.uid, // pos2
          "x": 30,
          "y": 31
     }
}
```

This can't work. First of all, in pos 1, you probably mean

```
animatedObjects = {
    userPosition:{
        uid : 
    }
}
```

otherwise you're creating `animatedObjects['userPosition.uid']` instead of `animatedObjects.userPosition.uid`.

Second, in pos 2, you are trying to initialize a variable with the object your just creating. This can't work, as there is no reference to pass. (There is no `this` context in a plain object, you can only pass them by reference when they are created, but not during creation).